# EC2 machine abruptly terminating right after start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was in the process of shrinking the size of the EBS volume attached to my ec2 machine. There are many tutorials on how to do this ([here is the one I used](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-volume/)).

The gist is that, I create a snapshot of the actual drive, and small empty volume. I then copy the content of the snapshot to the small drive via `sudo rsync -aHAXxSP /mnt/snap/ /mnt/small`.

When checking the contents of the small drive, it seems like it contains all of the folders/files in the original drive.

At the end, after detaching all volumes and attaching the smallest volume, when starting the ec2 instance, it terminates after initializing. 
When I get the reason for the termination it says `Instance initiated shutdown`:

```
AI2s-MBP-7:~ i-danielk$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-e0ef0910  
RESERVATIONS    645962089403    r-440c95a5
GROUPS  sg-4cdf6427 zfei_profiler
INSTANCES   0   x86_64  tOGHd1424650611612  True    xen ami-146e2a7c    i-e0ef0910  r3.2xlarge  zfei_profiler   2015-08-23T01:56:40.000Z            /dev/xvda   ebs     hvm
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPINGS /dev/xvda
EBS 2015-08-23T01:55:56.000Z    False   attached    vol-1d08fcf0
MONITORING  disabled
PLACEMENT   us-east-1c      default
SECURITYGROUPS  sg-4cdf6427 zfei_profiler
STATE   80  stopped
STATEREASON Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown    Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown
TAGS    Name    WIKI_TACL_MERGE
```

Any idea how can I figure out the real reason for my instance shutdown?

Update1: this is really weird ... the "Instance Settings > Get System Log" shows nothing. Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Update2: Both cases (original volume, and the small volume) were added as `/dev/xvda` (I tried `/dev/sda` but it didn't accept it).

Update3: Here is the content `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. Based on what I see, there is nothing problematic (and nothing needs to be changed).

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-167-76-117 target]$ cat /boot/grub/grub.conf
# created by imagebuilder
default=0
timeout=1
hiddenmenu

title Amazon Linux 2014.09 (3.14.33-26.47.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.33-26.47.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=ttyS0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
initrd /boot/initramfs-3.14.33-26.47.amzn1.x86_64.img

title Amazon Linux 2014.09 (3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=ttyS0
initrd /boot/initramfs-3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64.img
```

And this is `/etc/fstab`:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-167-76-117 target]$ cat /etc/fstab
#
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0
```

Comment: Which volume were you resizing? When you say "after detaching all volumes", did you detach the Root volume? Did you attach the new volume with the same device identifier (eg /dev/xvda or /dev/sda1)?

Comment: Have you reviewed the boot/system log, available in the AWS console?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this is really weird ... the "Instance Settings > Get System Log" shows nothing. Screenshot added.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein good point. Both cases the root was added to `/dev/xvda`.

Comment: It would appear that your root volume is not a successful copy, or is not being mounted such that it boots again. Can I ask your particular use-case for needing to shrink the boot volume? Storage costs are not that expensive (10c/GB/month).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Well I tried `rsync` twice to make sure we have everything copied and it looked fine to me. I will add the output of `rsync` here as well, in a few mins. 
The current size is 1024 GB, and I want to reduce it to 200GB. Isn't it big? (I thin EBS volumes are expensive; right?)

Comment: It might be some magic Linux stuff involving boot blocks (which is the case with Windows). Yes, that volume is big! FYI, it's generally a good idea to put data on a separate volume to make it easier to rebuilt a boot volume, speed up backups, etc.