# AMAZON EBS reduce volume size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reduce

I reduced the EBS volume size, following this tutorial: http://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-volume/

Then atach the reduced EBS to EC2 instance, but when status is "running", immediately the status change to "stopping" and shutdown the instance.

Could someone help me if you know what may be the problem please.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [EC2 machine abruptly terminating right after start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172838/ec2-machine-abruptly-terminating-right-after-start)

Answer (score 0):

When I am creating a volume from a snapshot but I want to decrease the size the there is an error.

[image]